# How to add shortcut for a specific action in imagej?

Tags: image-processing

In `imagej` I need to use `Process` -> `Math` -> `Set` a lot.
Is there a way to assign a shortcut for this action such as `Shift` + `anykey`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Plugins > Shortcut > Add Shortcut...`

In my distribution (Fiji) I have two commands called `Set...`, and if that's the case for you, a little guess-and-checking may be necessary to get the right one.